# How to remove previous pages from memory?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using an implementation of Master/Detail in my Forms app. The problem is that even after I change pages the previous one is still running, I even had to do some inactive/isActive code in order to stop the code execution of those pages.

This is how I change pages:

```
        public void GoTo(Page page)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
            IsPresented = false;
            UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        }
```

Then I do:

`Application.Current.HomePage.GoTo(new ServiceSelectionPage());`

But the previous page is kept running. What am I doing wrong? Or how do I remove those pages from memory? I tried setting `Detail = null` to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: YOu should not create multiple navigation pages, just one, and then use PushAsync and PopAsync, also then you can Remove it and it usually will free the removed pages

Comment: Do you mean instead of `Detail = new Nav...` I'd do that only once and for all other calls I'd do `Detail.Navigation.Push...`? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to do, one navigation page, multiple content pages. When you first created a navigation page the Navigation will be available in all the rest of pages, you don't even need to reference the detail page

Comment: Alright, I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with that is that now the user is allowed to go back and my top bar changes. That's not my intended behavior. I want neither the user being able to return nor to change the top bar. That's why I was changing the detail page with the new one. Any ideas for this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Just remove the navigation bar, create an empty or loader Navigation page and when you Push your new page Remove the old one

Comment: Yup, I've just done that and that seems to be the way to go. Please post that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design. You could:

- Set their instances to null, then wait for garbage collection. You could force it with `GC.Collect();` - but it's not guaranteed.
- Reuse pages instances (use same Page instance and only change current BindingContext). You could use custom Page Factory for that.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's not guaranteed how can I make sure?